# Why does using cache on streaming Datasets fail with "AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, spark-structured-streaming

```scala
SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:/tmp/spark")
  .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "C:/tmp/spark/spark-checkpoint")
  .appName("my-test")
  .getOrCreate
  .readStream
  .schema(schema)
  .json("src/test/data")
  .cache
  .writeStream
  .start
  .awaitTermination
```

While executing this sample in Spark 2.1.0 I got error.
Without the `.cache` option it worked as intended but with `.cache` option i got:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
FileSource[src/test/data]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:33)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForBatch(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:33)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSupported(QueryExecution.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$cacheQuery$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:2479)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.cache(Dataset.scala:2489)
at org.me.App$.main(App.scala:23)
at org.me.App.main(App.scala)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't think that just not using cache is the solution.

Comment: Martin, feel free to participate on the comments on [SPARK-20927](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20927?focusedCommentId=16334363&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16334363) about the need of caching on streaming computations

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your (very interesting) case boils down to the following line (that you can execute in `spark-shell`):

```
scala> :type spark
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> spark.readStream.text("files").cache
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
FileSource[files]
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:297)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:36)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:34)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForBatch(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:34)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSupported(QueryExecution.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$cacheQuery$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:2603)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.cache(Dataset.scala:2613)
  ... 48 elided
```

The reason for this turned out quite simple to explain (no pun to Spark SQL's `explain` intended).

`spark.readStream.text("files")` creates a so-called **streaming Dataset**.

```
scala> val files = spark.readStream.text("files")
files: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> files.isStreaming
res2: Boolean = true
```

Streaming Datasets are the foundation of Spark SQL's [Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).

As you may have read in Structured Streaming's [Quick Example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example):

> And then start the streaming computation using `start()`.

Quoting the scaladoc of DataStreamWriter's [start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@start():org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery):

> **start(): StreamingQuery** Starts the execution of the streaming query, which will continually output results to the given path as new data arrives.

So, you have to use `start` (or `foreach`) to start the execution of the streaming query. You knew it already.

But...there are [Unsupported Operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations) in Structured Streaming:

> In addition, there are some Dataset methods that will not work on streaming Datasets. They are actions that will immediately run queries and return results, which does not make sense on a streaming Dataset.
>
> If you try any of these operations, you will see an AnalysisException like "operation XYZ is not supported with streaming DataFrames/Datasets".

That looks familiar, *doesn't it?*

`cache` is **not** in the list of the unsupported operations, but that's because it has simply been overlooked (I reported [SPARK-20927](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20927) to fix it).

`cache` should have been in the list as it **does** execute a query before the query gets registered in Spark SQL's CacheManager.

Let's go deeper into the depths of Spark SQL...*hold your breath*...

`cache` [is](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2612) `persist` while `persist` [requests the current CacheManager to cache the query](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2602):

```
sparkSession.sharedState.cacheManager.cacheQuery(this)
```

While caching a query `CacheManager` **does** [execute it](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L104):

```
sparkSession.sessionState.executePlan(planToCache).executedPlan
```

which we **know** is not allowed since it is `start` (or `foreach`) to do so.

*Problem solved!*

Comment: I thought that this is a bug so i reported it even sooner https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20865 , i just needed to confirm my toughs. Thanks.

Comment: Link to master is not realy relevant because the target code can change.
And I think it's what append in your links

Comment: @crak Correct. I should not have used master for the links. What do you think would be better? Seen links to specific versions in the past, but can't figure out how to do it on github today. Mind to offer some help? I'd appreciate.

Comment: I was wondering too, but because your link as no value when the code change, I would recommend to target a specific commit. Your post was write at T time so maybe it will not be relevant in future spark version.
I'm not chock that your post is true just at a specific date.

Comment: I don't really get the "problem solved"... Cache() can make sense : caching intermediate mini-batches, for various reasons : large mini-batches, complex computation re-used in many subsequent queries. 
So cache() may be relevant, and adding it to UnsupportedOperations does solve anything (but the clarity of the error message...)

Comment: @mathieu OK. You're right. It could be supported by it's not by design. Please note that Spark 2.3 is coming with another streaming engine (which may change things re caching).

Comment: @jackek -  are you still interested in how to link to something other than master in github ?  in case you are: here it is.  1) Look at top of page that has link to 'master' version of the file. You will see the full path. to the right are 2 buttons that read 'Find File' and 'Copy Path'.  To the left of the path (which is a series of clickable links to parent directories), you will see a button with the text 'master'. Now just click on that and you will see a drop down that lets you pick either a specific tag or branch to link to. Just choose one of those for a less 'volatile' link.