# How do we cache / persist dataset in spark structured streaming 2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I want to write three separate outputs on the one calculated dataset, For that I have to cache / persist my first dataset, else it is going to caculate the first dataset three times which increase my calculation time.

e.g.

```
FirstDataset // Get data from kafka;

SecondDataset = FirstDataSet.mapPartitions(Some Calculations);

ThirdDataset = SecondDataset.mapPartitions(Some Calculations);
```

Now I want to filter my ThirdDataset and output the filtered datasets for three different conditions with different logic.

```
ThirdDataset.filter(**Condition1**).writeStream().foreach(**SOMECALCULATIONS1**).outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(600000)).start();

ThirdDataset.filter(**Condition2**).writeStream().foreach(**SOMECALCULATIONS2**).outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(600000)).start();

ThirdDataset.filter(**Condition3**).writeStream().foreach(**SOMECALCULATIONS3**).outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(600000)).start();
```

Now for each writestream ThirdDataset is calculating, If I cache ThirdDataset then it will not calculate thrice.

But when I do `ThirdDataset.cache()` it thows me following error,

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Queries with streaming sources must be executed with
>   writeStream.start();;

Can anyone please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Use foreachbatch sink and do a cache in there on the dataframe/dataset!

Answer (score 0):

Cache does not make sense with streaming dataset.

[SPARK-20865](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20865)

You may need to change the approach.

something like

```
ThirdDataset.writeStream().foreach(**SOMECALCULATIONS BASED ON CONDITION**).outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(600000)).start();
```

[cache on streaming datasets fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062092/why-does-using-cache-on-streaming-datasets-fail-with-analysisexception-queries)